# Strange eclipse display issues

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers for most of my coding, html, css, php etc etc. Recently however I have noticed an issue where after doing a combination of "something" the display of my files completely screws up and does all sorts of weird things.

For example if I try and add a `<a href="#"></a>` on starting to do it the characters just start going all over the place and giving me display issues like that shown in the attached screenshot.

It's a little tricky to explain exactly what's happening but eclipse basically becomes unusable as each keypress seems to do something random and mess up the page even more.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? I'm using a mac on Snow Leopard with Eclipse Indigo.

[image]

Comment: An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException that error appears in the log I think if that helps at all.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you on? I'd simply try updating, bugs are fixed all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update this. To resolve this issue I ended up downloading the latest version of eclipse and overwriting the eclipse directing with this. I tried just doing an update but this did not work so I'm guessing I had some corrupt files or something.

The good thing about eclipse is that you have a workspace folder that is essentially separate, so if you replace eclipse you can just re-import your old workspace.

ALl seems to be working as normal so far!